# Configuring base layers in GeoNetwork?

Tags: geoserver, geonetwork

How can I configure base layers in Geonetwork 3.0.2?

I have tried to edit config-gui.xml and config-viewer.xml, but nothing happens.

Does it only work for the old version?

Answer (score 1):

That's for the old UIs. Now you can configure it on the settings, editing the context as a string.

More information on the GeoNetwork documentation: http://geonetwork-opensource.org/manuals/trunk/eng/users/customizing-application/search-ui/configdefault.html

Comment: The GeoNetwork documentation referenced doesn't make it clear how to configure base layers.  Perhaps it's obvious to a developer, but not to a maintainer.